# What index to be added in MongoDB to support $elemMatch query on embedded document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose we have a following document

```
{
   embedded:[
   {
      email:"abc@abc.com",
      active:true
   },
   {
      email:"def@abc.com",
      active:false
   }]
}
```

What indexing should be used to support $elemMatch query on email and active field of embedded doc.

Update on question :-

```
db.foo.aggregate([{"$match":{"embedded":{"$elemMatch":{"email":"abc@abc.com","active":true}}}},{"$group":{_id:null,"total":{"$sum":1}}}],{explain:true});
```

on querying this i am getting following output of explain on aggregate :-

```
{
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "embedded" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "email" : "abc@abc.com",
                        "active" : true
                    }
                }
            },
            "fields" : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "$noFieldsNeeded" : 1
            },
            "planError" : "InternalError No plan available to provide stats"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "$const" : null
            },
            "total" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

I think mongodb internally not using index for this query.

Thanx in advance :)

Update on output of `db.foo.stats()`

```
db.foo.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test.foo",
    "count" : 2,
    "size" : 480,
    "avgObjSize" : 240,
    "storageSize" : 8192,
    "numExtents" : 1,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 8192,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 24528,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 8176,
        "embedded.email_1_embedded.active_1" : 8176,
        "name_1" : 8176
    },
    "ok" : 1
}


db.foo.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.foo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "embedded.email" : 1,
            "embedded.active" : 1
        },
        "name" : "embedded.email_1_embedded.active_1",
        "ns" : "test.foo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_1",
        "ns" : "test.foo"
    }
]
```

Comment: Well you can pretty much just query whatever you want in just1 about every database I can think of. When it comes to "indexes", it really has nothing to do with the "structure" but is really all about the "query patterns" you regularly use. So how are you going to to query this on a regular basis. Which "field/fields" are present in your most common queries? That's what you decide on.

Answer (score 1):

Should you decide to stick to that data model and your queries, here's how to create indexes that match the query:

You can simply index `"embedded.email"`, or use a compound key of embedded indexes, i.e. something like

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({"embedded.email" : 1 });
  - or -
> db.foo.ensureIndex({"embedded.email" : 1, "embedded.active" : 1});
```

Indexing boolean fields is often not too useful, since their selectivity is low.

Comment: i have applied this indexing but on explaining query mongo doesn't uses it

Comment: It does use the index (`IXSCAN`) on my machine (MongoDB 3.0.0-rc8 x64 Win7). Your explain output contains an error - Is `foo` really the name of your collection? Have you tried with a simple find?

Comment: Yes it's foo. would you be able to list me a queries you are using that will be helpful. thax :)

Comment: The regular query? Just `db.foo.find({ "embedded" : { $elemMatch : {"email" : "abc@abc.com" }}}).explain();` You might want to check your server version. That internal error irritates me...

Comment: MongoDB 2.6.7, Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64bit

Comment: Hm, this looks like a true error to me, not a problem with the index. Maybe drop the collection, do a repair, re-insert the data, re-build the index and post the output of `db.foo.stats()` and `db.foo.getIndexes()`.

Comment: Cool doing it soon :) thax

Comment: you can check the outputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72466/discussion-between-mnemosyn-and-jugal).

Comment: This didn't exactly work out how you planned? So could you possibly remove "Neil's comment notwithstanding". Both because it kind of "stands" as the most valid thing said here ( hence protracted conversation ) and also makes you sound a little "glib", which I hope you really are not because there are too many people here who "think they are great" but couldn't hit a nail with a hammer to save their life  as an analogy. So do you want to be a white hat or a black hat?

Comment: To clear this up: I was answering the question of how to create such indexes, and the indexes seem valid. Since users with little MongoDB experience don't neccessarily know multikeys and compound indexes, I find this stands as the only constructive thing said here. Setting that aside, the "notwithstanding" might not have conveyed what I wanted it too - as a non-native speaker, it's sometimes hard to get the tone right. As a side note, I hope you me well enough to know that I'm not one of the guys unable to hit a nail with a hammer, to use that analogy.